# Burninate boost-logging

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

There is no real reason to keep [boost-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-logging) alive, since it has long been replaced by [boost-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-log). This creates duplication and confusion for users.

If the tags were merged, it may confuse users even more since API may not always be compatible.

Comment: If the 17 questions currently tagged with `boost-logging` are correctly tagged then you can't really get rid of it. You can't suggest that a tag be eliminated unless you have an alternative.

Comment: If the library has been replaced and is no longer in use, that should probably be mentioned in the wiki summary.

Answer (score 8):

> *"If the tags were merged, it may confuse users even more since API may not always be compatible."*

So, synonyms aren't an option because it'd cause confusion, and removal of [boost-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-logging) isn't either, since the tag *is* used correctly.

Since there is no grounded reason the tag should be removed, you can consider this answer a vote against the burnination of [boost-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-logging).

As [@Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298315/burninate-boost-logging/298317#comment215092_298315): A better alternative would be to edit the wiki summary to clarify that the library has been replaced (With a link to the replacement)